What is the background of the Information security site logo
I was looking at the information security stack exchange site logo and thought it looks pretty cool and appropriate.  I'm interested in how it was chosen, does it come from somewhere else or is it entirely original.


There were a number of posts as the SE design team consulted with the community to build this, but the concluding post is here.
